# Let $f(x)$ be twice differentiable function, with $f(x) = x$ has $3$ roots

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ is twice differentiable increasing  function everywhere such that $f(x) = x$ has $3$ distinct root $\alpha ,\beta$ and $\gamma$  $(\alpha  < \beta  < \gamma )$ . Let $h(x) = \underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\underset{n\,\,\,times}{\mathop{(f(f(...(f(x))))}}\,$.

(1)    If $f’’(x) > 0$ $\forall \,x\,\in \,(-\infty ,\beta )$,  $f”(x) < 0$ $ \forall x\,\in \,(\beta ,\infty ]\,$ and $f''(\beta )=0,\,$ then find $h(x)$

(2)    If $f(x)\ge x\,\forall \,x\,\in \,(-\infty ,\alpha ]\,\cup \,[\gamma ,\infty )$ and $f(x)\le x\,\forall \,x\,\in \,[\beta ,\gamma ]\,$ then find $h(x)$

I tried with a fucntion $k(x) = f(x)-x$ , such that $k(\beta)$ is $0$.
But how to do further.

Comment: what have you tried

Comment: not able to start

Answer (score 3):

(1)

Let us first consider the case $x\in(\beta,\infty)$.

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Note that $g''(x)<0$ on $x\in(\beta,\infty)$ and $g(\beta)=g(\gamma)=0$.

$\forall x\in(\beta,\gamma)$, $g(x)\ge 0$ since otherwise there exists $m\in[\beta,\gamma]$ s.t. $g(m)=\inf_{x\in[\beta,\gamma]}g(x)<0$, then $m\in(\beta,\gamma)$ and $g''(m)\le 0(\Rightarrow\Leftarrow)$

Moreover, $\forall x\in(\beta,\gamma),g(x)>0$ since otherwise $f(x)=x$.

Now, knowing that $g(x)\ge 0$ on $(\beta,\gamma)$ and $g(\gamma)=0$, we have $g'(\gamma)\le 0$. By integrating over $x$, we can obtain $\forall x>\gamma,g'(x)<0$ and $\forall x>\gamma, g(x)<0$.

Assume $\beta<x<\gamma$. $x<f(x)<f(\gamma)=\gamma$ since $g(x)>0$ on $(\beta,\gamma)$ and $f$ is increasing.

Assume $\gamma<x$. $\gamma=f(\gamma)<f(x)<x$ since $g(x)<0$ on $(\gamma,\infty)$ and $f$ is increasing.

-Here is what we've obtained up to now.

> $x\in(\beta,\gamma)\Rightarrow f(x)\in(x,\gamma)$ and $x\in(\gamma,\infty)\Rightarrow f(x)\in(\gamma,x)$

By monotone convergence theorem, $\forall x\in(\beta,\gamma),\exists h(x)\in(\beta,\gamma]$. Here, $f(h(x))=h(x)\Rightarrow g(h(x))=0\Rightarrow h(x)=\gamma$. Similarly, $\forall x\in(\gamma,\infty),h(x)=\gamma$. Of course, $h(\gamma)=\gamma$.

Use the same argument to show $h(x)=\alpha$ for $x\in(-\infty),\beta)$.

$h(\beta)=\beta$ of course, so $h$ is

> $h(x)=\begin{cases}\alpha,x<\beta\\ \beta,x=\beta\\ \gamma,x>\beta\end{cases}$

(2)

Assume $h(x)$ exists on $x\in(\gamma,\infty)$. Note that $\forall x>\gamma, f(x)\ge x$. Thus, $h(x)\ge x>\gamma$. This contradicts $f(h(x))=h(x)$. Therefore, $h$ is undefined on $(\gamma,\infty)$.

Let us then think when $x\in(\beta,\gamma)$. Observe that in the first block(yellow) I only used $f(x)\in(x,\gamma)$ to show $h(x)=\gamma$. It works here as well.

Similarly, you can do that on $(-\infty,\alpha)$ to obtain $h(x)=\alpha$.

$x\in(\alpha,\beta)$ is more difficult. $g$ should be either always positive or always negative on $(\alpha,\beta)$ since otherwise we have $x\in(\alpha,\beta)$ s.t. $g(x)=0$ but that cannot happen.

When $g$ is positive, $h(x)=\beta$ for $x\in(\alpha,\beta)$ since $f(x)\in(x,\beta)$ on that interval.

When $g$ is negative, $h(x)=\alpha$ for the same reason.

Therefore, we have two possible answers for (2). (In fact, we have possible examples to both of them)

> $h(x)=\begin{cases}\alpha,x\in(-\infty,\alpha]\\ \alpha\,or\,\beta,x\in(\alpha,\beta)\\ \beta,x=\beta\\ \gamma,x\in(\beta,\gamma]\\ \infty,x\in(\gamma,\infty)\end{cases}$

Comment: Wow, how does it happen that the question goes unanswered for 10 days and then two answers are suddenly posted at the same time? Well, if the OP decides they prefer yours, I'll delete mine to avoid clutter.

Comment: @J_P : Maybe other former bounty problems had been ended very recently so we were(at least I was) able to see this...so surprising that we posted answers in just 10 sec time gap.

Comment: To be honest, I was a bit unsure of my answer but when I saw yours, I concluded that mine can't be too wrong, so I just posted it since even if they're similar, it can't hurt for the OP see both. That's why the gap is only 10 sec. But it would've been close regardless.

Comment: Hi. You have written "Assume $\beta<x<\gamma$. $x<f(x)<f(\gamma)=\gamma$ since $g(x)>0$ on $(\beta,\gamma)$ and $f$ is increasing." How is $f$ increasing in $(\beta, \gamma)$? I understand $f(x)\gt x$ but how is $f(\gamma)\gt f(x)$?

Comment: @aarbee - It is given in the question that $f$ is increasing throughout the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the sequence defined by $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ where $f$ is increasing. Suppose $x_0<x_1$. Then it's straightforward by induction that $x_n<x_{n+1}$. Similarly, if $x_0>x_1$, then $x_n>x_{n+1}$. (The case $x_0=x_1$ is trivial.)

Suppose now we have a stationary point $\xi$, meaning that $f(\xi)=\xi$. If $x_0<\xi$, then by induction (as $f$ is increasing): $x_n<\xi\implies x_{n+1}=f(x_n)<f(\xi)=\xi$. Hence $x_n<\xi$. Similarly, when $x_0>\xi$ we get $x_n>\xi$.

Suppose that $\lim x_n=L$ exists. Then as $f$ is continuous: $L=\lim x_{n+1}=\lim f(x_n)=f(\lim x_n)=f(L)$. So if $x_n$ is convergent, the limit must be one of the stationary points of $f$.

Having established all this, notice that in your case $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are stationary points. The strategy in the following will be:

1. identify the possible cases for $x_0$,
2. given an $x_0$, find whether $x_1>x_0$ or $x_1<x_0$ to establish if $x_n$ increases or decreases,
3. find the appropriate stationary point if such a point exists,
4. conclude that $x_n$ either converges to that stationary point or diverges to $\pm\infty$,
5. since the limit of $x_n$ is just $\lim f(f(...(f(x_0))))$, that will be $h(x)$.

---

$(1)$ First notice that $f'(\beta)>1$ - if not, then from $f''(x)<0$ for $x>\beta$, we would have $f'(x)<1$ for $x>\beta$, so $f(x)<x$ there and $\gamma$ couldn't exist. The qualitative picture of $f$ is then this: it comes in from $-\infty$ less steeply that $x$, intersects $x$ at $\alpha$, curves up to hit $x$ at $\beta$, curves back down to hit it at $\gamma$ and then goes on to $+\infty$ less steeply than $x$.
Since $f(x)>x$ on $(-\infty,\alpha)\cup(\beta,\gamma)$, we have that there $x_1=f(x_0)>x_0$, so $x_n$ is increasing. If we begin in the other two intervals, $(\alpha,\beta)\cup(\gamma,\infty)$, we analogously get $x_1<x_0$, so $x_n$ is decreasing. Since it's obvious which stationary points correspond to which case, we get:

1. $x_0\in(-\infty,\beta): h(x_0)=\alpha$
2. $x_0\in(\beta,\infty): h(x_0)=\gamma$
3. $x_0=\beta: h(x_0)=\beta$

---

$(2)$ There's a bit of a problem here. I don't know if this was a typo, but your conditions leave unspecified whether $f(x)>x$ or $<x$ on $(\alpha,\beta)$. I'll just suppose $f(x)<x$ and the other option is very similar. Again, all you need to do is figure out where $f(x)<x$ and where $f(x)>x$ - in this case, $<$ is on $(\alpha,\beta)\cup(\beta,\gamma)$ and $>$ is on $(-\infty,\alpha)\cup(\gamma,\infty)$. Therefore:

1. $x_0\in(-\infty,\beta): h(x_0)=\alpha$
2. $x_0\in[\beta,\gamma): h(x_0)=\beta$
3. $x_0=\gamma: h(x_0)=\gamma$
4. $x_0\in(\gamma,\infty): h(x_0)=\infty$

Comment: +1 for the effort to simplify the proof