# If $f(x) = x$ has $3$ distinct roots, how to find $\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\underset{n\,\,\,times}{\mathop{(f(f(...(f(x))))}}\,$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, contest-math

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> Let $f(x)$ is twice differentiable increasing  function everywhere such that $f(x) = x$ has $3$ distinct root $\alpha ,\beta$ and $\gamma$  $(\alpha  < \beta  < \gamma )$ . Let $h(x) = \underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\underset{n\,\,\,times}{\mathop{(f(f(...(f(x))))}}\,$.
>
> - $(1)$    If $f’’(x) > 0$ $\forall \,x\,\in \,(-\infty ,\beta )$,  $f”(x) < 0$ $ \forall x\,\in \,(\beta ,\infty ]\,$ and $f''(\beta )=0,\,$ then find $h(x)$
> - $(2)$    If $f(x)\ge x\,\forall \,x\,\in \,(-\infty ,\alpha ]\,\cup \,[\gamma ,\infty )$ and $f(x)\le x\,\forall \,x\,\in \,[\beta ,\gamma ]\,$ then find $h(x)$

This question already has two answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254895/let-fx-be-twice-differentiable-function-with-fx-x-has-3-roots) but they are quite notation heavy. So, I am not able to follow. I wish somebody could explain in simple terms.

I will write what I have tried.

I drew a line $y=x$. $f(x)$ would meet it at three points $\alpha, \beta, 
\gamma$.

For the first part, since $f''>0$ for $x<\beta$, it means $f(x)$ is concave upward ($f(x)<x$), and for $x>\beta$, it's concave downward ($f(x)>x$). From this how can we calculate $h(x)$? Do we need to know exact $f(x)$ for this?

For the second part, I think $f(x)$ would be concave upward when $x$ is between $\beta$ and $\gamma$ and at other points, $f(x)$ is above the line $y=x$. Again, not able to find $f(x)$ or $h(x)$ from here.

Comment: I think my explanation above is incorrect. Since $f(x)$ is increasing, it can't be concave downward I think.

Comment: In that case, it can't be concave upward as well I think.

Comment: So, does that mean it's a constant function for the large part?

Comment: Does that mean $f(x)=h(x)$?

Comment: Taking examples of $y(x)=\pm e^{\pm x}$ show that a strictly increasing or decreasing function can be concave or convex

Comment: @Moko19 oh yes, thanks.

Comment: The second part doesn't mention anything about the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$. Is its nature implied on its own?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $f(x)$ be twice differentiable function, with $f(x) = x$ has $3$ roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254895/let-fx-be-twice-differentiable-function-with-fx-x-has-3-roots)

Comment: @Artic_Char I have already linked this in my question.

Comment: Since you did not explain how those answers does not satisfy you, it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @Arctic_Char, those questions have introduced a lot of notations and symbols. That's confusing me further. I was wondering if someone could explain the question conceptually.