# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to(e^{-1})^+}\frac{e^{\frac{\ln(1+\ln x)}x}}{x-e^{-1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, contest-math

> Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to(e^{-1})^+}\dfrac{e^{\dfrac{\ln(1+\ln x)}x}}{x-e^{-1}}$

It's a $\dfrac00$ form.

**Approach$1$:** L'Hopital$$\lim_{x\to(e^{-1})^+}\dfrac{e^{\dfrac{\ln(1+\ln x)}x}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac1{1+\ln x}-\ln(1+\ln x)}{x^2}}1\\=\lim_{x\to(e^{-1})^+}e^{\dfrac{\ln(1+\ln x)}x}\cdot\dfrac{1-\ln(1+\ln x)^{1+\ln x}}{x^2(1+\ln x)}$$

Again this is indeterminate. So, I abandoned this approach.

**Approach$2$:** Series expansion.$$\ln(1+\ln x)=\ln x-\frac{(\ln x)^2}2+\cdots$$

This is to be divided by $x$. Don't think I am going anywhere with this.

Any hint please?

Comment: Not certain I understand what is happening in the second fraction of the derived portion of Approach 1.  How did $\ln(1+\ln x)$ appear in the exponent location?

Comment: @abiessu thanks for the feedback. I'll make an edit.

Comment: You can simplify the numerator exponent. The limit looks to be 0.

Comment: @abiessu Hi. Is my approach understandable now?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Hi. Can you elaborate? Which numerator exponent are you talking about?

Comment: @aarbee Perhaps: $$\mathrm{e^\frac{ln(ln(x)+1)}{x}=(ln(x)+1)^\frac{1}{x}}$$

Comment: It seems like you are exchanging a $\frac 00$ form for a $0^0$ form with that step.  Yes, I can see the connection now, but I think I would prefer to deal with the prior form instead.

Comment: @TymaGaidash oh yeah, that's a wonderful hint. I'll try with this, thanks.

Comment: @abiessu ya, that's why I abandoned that approach.

Comment: @TymaGaidash that form is also giving the exact same result!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let $t=x-\frac 1e$. Then we have-
$$L=\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac {\left( \ln(1+et)\right)^{\frac {e}{et+1}}}{t}$$ since for any possible $k$, $e^{\ln k}=k$.
Now let $et=u$, then limit turns into:
$$L=e\lim_{u \to 0^{+}} \frac {\left(\ln(1+u)\right)^{\frac {e}{1+u}}}{u}=e\lim_{u \to 0^{+}} \left(\frac {\ln(1+u)}{u}\right)^{\frac {e}{1+u}} u^{\frac {e}{1+u}-1}$$
Now from the well known result that $\frac {\ln(1+x)}{x}=1-\frac x2 +O(x^2)$, we can substitute value of $u$ to evaluate limit and find that $$L=0$$

---

Perhaps it is note-worthy here that your approach 2 is, in fact, incorrect. Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$ should only be written around $x=0$, and not in any neighborhood of $x$. However in my solution you'll notice that the series has been applied keeping in mind the conditions.

Comment: thankyou. Do you mind having a look at the following question too?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4211954/if-fx-x-has-3-distinct-roots-how-to-find-undersetn-to-infty-math

Comment: thankyou for the wonderful ending note. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Let $1+\log x =t$ so that $t\to 0^+$. The expression under limit is then transformed into $$e\cdot\frac{e^{(\log t) /e^{t-1}} }{e^t-1} =e\cdot\frac{t^{e^{1-t}}} {t}\cdot\frac{e^t-1}{t}$$ The last fraction tends to $1$ and hence desired limit is equal to the limit of $$et^{e^{1-t}-1}$$ The exponent in above expression tends to $e-1>0$ and the base $t\to 0^+$ hence $t^{e^{1-t}-1}\to 0$. The desired limit is thus $0$.